# Symfony2 assets:install says: "The target directory web does not exist" but it does.

Tags: symfony

When I run the command "assets : install --symlink " local running, but on the server the following error occurs :

*The project is on github*

**local:**

[image]

**Remote server (production server):**

[image: the target directory "web" does not exist]

What can be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Check permissions on `web` directory.

Comment: Check the correct case of the web folder ie Web

Comment: I had the same problem on a cheap, shared webhost. Using the absolute path on the server to the `web` directory solved my problem (no idea why). You could try to execute `php app/console assets:install --symlink ~/public_html/trendytouristmx/web`.