# "assets:install" command fails with error "The target directory "web" does not exist", why?

Tags: php, docker, symfony, symlink

I am running a Symfony3 application inside a Docker container. I have created a `CommonBundle` with all the resources (js, css, images). This resources are symlinked to another path as shown below:

```
$ docker exec -u www-data -it dockeramp_php_1 ls -la oneview_symfony/src/CommonBundle/Resources/public
total 8
drwxrwsr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 23 21:09 .
drwxr-sr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 23 20:54 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     www-data   32 Feb 23 21:09 css -> /var/www/html/public_html/styles
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     www-data   32 Feb 23 21:09 images -> /var/www/html/public_html/images
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     www-data   28 Feb 23 21:08 js -> /var/www/html/public_html/js
```

The directory `oneview_symfony/web` does exists and it's writable by `www-data` as shown below:

```
$ docker exec -u www-data -it dockeramp_php_1 ls -la oneview_symfony/web
total 64
drwxrwsr-x 3 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 23 20:50 .
drwxrwsr-x 9 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 23 21:16 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data  3319 Feb 23 16:45 .htaccess
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data   631 Feb 23 16:45 app.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data   843 Feb 23 16:45 app_dev.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data  2092 Feb 23 16:45 apple-touch-icon.png
drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 23 20:50 bundles
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 21486 Feb 23 20:50 config.php
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data  6518 Feb 23 16:45 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data   116 Feb 23 16:45 robots.tx
```

I am trying to install the assets `relative` or `symlink` switching values on the `composer.json` file:

```
{
    ...
    "extra": {
        ... 
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    }
}
```

I am trying to publish the assets running the following command and ending up with the error below:

```
$ docker exec -u www-data -it dockeramp_php_1 php oneview_symfony/bin/console assets:install


  [InvalidArgumentException]                  
  The target directory "web" does not exist.
```

What I am missing here?

There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961341/symfony2-assetsinstall-says-the-target-directory-web-does-not-exist-but-it-d) but without answer so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try this command instead:

```
$ docker exec -u www-data -it dockeramp_php_1 php oneview_symfony/bin/console assets:install web
```

If that doesn't work, try the full path to the `web` directory.
Let us know if that works. Not sure if that will fix the problem, but please try it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I never think on use the full path which did works, using only `web` doesn't I tried that one before but as said adding the full path to web make the command to work

Answer (score 2):

Configure variable for `assets` command.

Add `public-dir` to `composer.json`

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "public-dir": "web",
    ...
},
```

Because `assets` command relies on it ([view code on github](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/b2ab2a295cdfa64c6757c0dd043f7381374c9602/Command/AssetsInstallCommand.php#L313))

Look:

```
        $defaultPublicDir = 'public';

        // ...

        if (isset($composerConfig['extra']['public-dir'])) {
            return $composerConfig['extra']['public-dir'];
        }

        return $defaultPublicDir;
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to install assets in Symfony 4 with the old Symfony3 directory structure getting:

```
Error thrown while running command "assets:install". Message: "The target directory "public" does not exist."
```

The same fix Alvin Bunk provided works:

```
$ bin/console assets:install web
```

Just manually provide the old target path

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the exact line

`app/console assets:install` or `bin/console assets:install`

(depends on your version) since it takes the path of the command as reference.