# Symfony deploy with capistrano throw "The target directory "web" does not exist." on assets install

Tags: symfony, deployment, server, composer-php, capistrano

I have a symfony system that i`m trying to deploy to with capistrano. The connection is through ssh.

The function that throws the error is symfony:assets:install as it looks below:

```
php /var/www/xx/releases/20200415083534/app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

It is throwing the following error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                  
  The target directory "web" does not exist.
```

As you would expect the folder is right there - my user is the owner and have rights for it.
If I go to this exact folder /20200415083534 and run the same script as above it does install the assets as expected.

The composer extra looks like so:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": [
      {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
      },
      {
        "file": "app/config/parameters_prod.yml",
        "dist-file": "app/config/parameters_prod.yml.dist"
      }
    ],
    "branch-alias": {
      "dev-master": "2.8.*"
    }
  }
```

Any ideas?

P.S. I have checked this one 
["assets:install" command fails with error "The target directory "web" does not exist", why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426517/assetsinstall-command-fails-with-error-the-target-directory-web-does-not-e) 
as it has the same error, but the situation is different and his solution doesn't work for my case.

Comment: I think you need to go into 20200415083534 folder before run this script

Comment: Can anyone explain what are the downvotes for? I`m a bit confused.

Comment: I don't know why, but can you answer me.

Comment: @GaryHoubre This doesn't seem to work as "symfony:assets:install" is using exactly that command - php /var/www/xx/releases/20200415083534/app/console assets:install web --symlink

It doesn't matter if I change the directory before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may sound a bit stupid, but I did resolved the issue by adding a space in the console app path in deploy.rb file. ( I think the issue is somewhere else, but that workaround did it in my case )
It looks like:

```
set :symfony_console_path, " app/console"
```

now.

This has changed the command line to:

```
php /var/www/xx/releases/20200415083534/ app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

Which does actually execute as expected.

Hope this helps someone banging his head on that issue (just as I did for a few days).